# Keychain issues after Sierra

Tags: keychain, performance, macos

I've updated to MacOS Sierra a few days ago, and it has been really unstable (a lot of freezes and hangs, specially in XCode).

I noticed that in Console, the following two lines appear repeatedly, for different apps and services:

```
switching to keychain-db: /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain (0 1 1 1)
not switching as we're not in ~/Library/Keychains/: /Library/Keychains/System.keychain (0)
```

Is there any issue with keychain? Could that be causing the freezes?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. It appears mostly for twitter app, but still.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a smart card, YubiKey, or similar security device, would you?  Is `scdaemon` running?

Answer (score 3):

tldr: No, you don't have an issue going on with keychain. Yes this could be a contribution to the hanging and very slow systems right now.

I have also been experiencing SERIOUS freezes with everything. I also have these same log messages for nearly every currently running application/task being spammed into the console at a ridiculous rate. Running terminal commands takes 10+ seconds in between input and forget a `git status` with this.

Apple has always had an unreasonable fetching rate for AddressBook, Calendar, and other apps which always cause these log issues since el capitan.

Currently Safari and WebKit is being added into this mix with it being quite unstable and has been since Sierra's beta throwing these log errors.

```
<compose failure [shared UUID]>
```

The log rate is quite substantial and is more than likely the reason or atleast a major part in our very slow systems right now.

Mid 2012 Macbook Pro Retina 2.6GHz Intel quad core here and I've never had it this bad.

Comment: to make the console somehow readable, either change the log mode systemwide, use the console+filters (i dont since i dont like the new console) or use terminal with `log stream --level=debug --predicate 'eventMessage contains "keyword"'` or/and use `subsystem contains com.apple.xxx` to filter out the issue root

Comment: according to man you can set the log systemwide level with `sudo log config --mode "level:default"` but I don't see any change in amount of useless info in the console despite setting it to different settings (although a reboot/relogin might be necessary), I don't know which job reloads the logd (I assume which is responsible for syslog job)

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it could be causing the freezes, something else would be causing the freezes. You should only worry about that log in the console if you are having problems specifically with the mail app, contacts, or calendars app(related to syncing or retrieving data from server).

Comment: Agreed- I don't think those messages are related to the hanging/freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (temporary) possible solution:

`ln -s ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

Comment: I already have both login.keychain-db and login.keychain files.